# Physical example for a non-linear mass-spring system?

Tags: spring, differential-equations, vibrations, non-linear-systems

Let's say there is a mass-spring system:

${\frac {\mathrm {d} ^{2}x}{\mathrm {d} t^{2}}}+2\zeta \omega _{0}{\frac {\mathrm {d} x}{\mathrm {d} t}}+\omega _{0}^{\,2}x=F$

I would like to ask for a real-life physical example that makes the above system non-linear. Here $F$ could be any function, e.g. $F=(2\zeta \omega _{0}{\frac {\mathrm {d} x}{\mathrm {d} t})^2}$.

It would be ideal if the physical example is about a spring-mounted cylinder oscillating in fluid.

Comment: This post (v1) seems like a list question.

Comment: @Qmechanic Hi. Would you kindly offer a relevant link?

Comment: Are you able to set a mass-spring system whose equation of motions is given as the one above with $F=0$? If yes, then you just have to assume that the spring is non linear (for example its force is $-k_1x-k_2x^3$).

Comment: @ZhongluLin You already have an example, the mass-spring system. Hooke's law is just an approximation, real springs are non-linear.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel :p ok then